# How to change all strings in python file from snake_case to camelCase in sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I've tried some sed patterns like this from commandlinefu

```
sed -r "s/('[a-z]+)_([a-z])([a-z]+)/\1\U\2\L\3/"
```

But somehow it's not working. For one thing they forgot the digits, which I can fix, but this pattern works for one underscore only. So for example if I have a string in file

> 'foo_bar_foo'

it will convert in to

> 'fooBar_foo'

. Which is not what I want (I want `'fooBarFoo'`)

I only want to change strings in file, not the variable names or anything else.
So for example this

```
delta_limits=Limits(general_settings['signal_lower_limit']
```

Should become this

```
delta_limits=Limits(general_settings['signalLowerLimit']
```

Comment: What is it you want? `'fooBarFoo'` or `'FooBarFoo'`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas 'fooBarFoo'

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Well, no. Not exactly. Because I don't want to change variable names. Only strings in source file.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus I've just did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to change `_x` to `X` as long as it occurs inside `'...'` strings.

Then, with GNU `sed`, you could do:

```
sed -E ":1;s/^(([^']|'[^']*')*'[^']*)_([^'])/\1\u\3/;t1"
```

That is replace a `_X` following `'...` itself following a sequence of either non-quotes or matched quotes.

Which on an input like:

```
foo_bar 'ab_cd_ef gh_ij' zz_zz 'aa_bb''
delta_limits=Limits(general_settings['signal_lower_limit']
```

gives:

```
foo_bar 'abCdEf ghIj' zz_zz 'aaBb'
delta_limits=Limits(general_settings['signalLowerLimit']
```

That assumes you don't have strings embedding single quotes (as in `'foo\'bar'`). If so, you'd need to account for those `\'` escapes with:

```
sed -E ":1;s/^(([^']|'([^\']|\\\\.)*')*'([^\']|\\\\.)*)_([^'])/\1\u\5/;t1"
```

(also accounts for `'foo\\'`).

That still doesn't cover `"foo'bar"` quotes or backslash-continued lines or `python's` `'''it's a multi-line quote'''`. You'd need a `python` parser to be able to cover all the cases.

For your particular case,

```
sed -E ":1;s/('\w*)_(\w)/\1\u\2/g;t1"
```

May also be enough (only replaces the `_X` that follow `'\w*`). That's the GNU `sed` equivalent (except for what `\w` exactly matches) of [Glenn's `perl` approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/226602).

Comment: Seems to work, can you explain how it works also? I know basics of regex, so maybe this wouldn't be that hard to explain.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use perl for this:

```
perl -pe "1 while s/('\w+)_([^']*)/\$1\\u\$2/" <<END
my_variable = 'a_string_with_snake_case_inside'
delta_llimits=Limits(general_settings['signal_lower_limit']
END
```

```
my_variable = 'aStringWithSnakeCaseInside'
delta_limits=Limits(general_settings['signalLowerLimit']
```

That means: while the search and replace continues to find a match, "1" (a no-op that returns true)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I think this should be possible without perl. I could do that in python If I wanted to, or Java, or any language I know.

Comment: No problem. perl's just a program (like sed) that happens to be good at text manipulation.

Comment: I thought that perl is a programming language... Isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is. So is sed.

Comment: Oh, thank you for enlightening me! I haven't realized that.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html